# Error Code: 3685. Illegal argument to a regular expression

Tags: mysql-8.0

I am trying to find an exact number in MySQL 8.0 using the below SQL statement

```
SELECT * FROM rulebook.node__body 
WHERE body_value REGEXP "[[:<:]]DVP[[:>:]]";
```

[image]

when i am running the above SQL statement i am getting below error

> Error Code: 3685. Illegal argument to a regular expression

could you please anyone tell me where i am  making mistake.

Comment: Why are you using `REGEXP` on what appears to be numeric data?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i have given an example  actually i want to look for a word

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i have changed my SQL statement and table could you please have a look

Comment: @ZahidHussain: what are you trying to look for? Anything containing "<" and DVP and ">" ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am trying to look for exact DVP

Answer (score 45):

This question will probably become more popular as adoption of MySQL 8.0 increases and previously-stored SQL queries using `REGEXP` start to break.

According to [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Regular Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html), "MySQL implements regular expression support using International Components for Unicode (ICU)."

According to [MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Regular Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html), "MySQL uses Henry Spencer's implementation of regular expressions."

Therefore, since you are using MySQL 8.0, rather than using `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`, you can now use `\b`. Your query might look like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM `rulebook`.`node__body`
 WHERE `body_value` REGEXP "\\bDVP\\b"
     ;
```

Comment: This worked for me, however using it in php I had to escape each of the two backslashes ending up with '\\\\bDVP\\\\b'

Comment: @SuprMan, Thanks, I was trying with double and didn't worked, but with four backslashes, it worked.

Comment: hm... it works for me with 2 backslashes, @amir22 maybe because of MySQL version? 5.7 for me.

Answer (score 2):

In php() replace special symbol as four "backslashes + b"

Example:

```
$where = "regexp '[[:<:]](" . $custom_category . ")[[:>:]]'";
```

Replace with:

```
$where = "regexp '\\\\b(" . $custom_category . ")\\\\b'";
```

Parentheses don't matter...

If you wont replace recursive in your sites, use this script, for search and replace in all php files this pattern:

```
# find /var/www/user/data/www/site.com/ -type f -name '*.php' | xargs sed -i  's/\[\[\:[<|>]\:\]\]/\\\\\\\\b/g'
```

Comment: why shouldn't he use [[:<:]] ?

Comment: [[:<:]] and [[:>:]] are not supported in MySQL 8.0.4 and higher:

 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html


"Prior to MySQL 8.0.4, MySQL used the Henry Spencer regular expression library to support regular expression operations, rather than International Components for Unicode (ICU). The Spencer library supports word-beginning and word-end boundary markers ([[:<:]] and [[:>:]] notation). ICU does not. For ICU, you can use \b to match word boundaries; double the backslash because MySQL interprets it as the escape character within strings."

Answer (score 0):

This little python code could help you find the problematic files.
it is auto-replace so make sure you keep a backup of all your files just in case
just run this in your root directory or change the path to root

```html
import os
import re
import chardet

root_directory = "/"  # Replace this with the root directory of your website
pattern = re.compile(r'\[\[:<:\]\]|\[\[:>:\]\]')
replacement = r'\b'
file_types = ('.php')

count = 0
files_modified = []

def read_file_with_encoding(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        raw_data = f.read()
    detected_encoding = chardet.detect(raw_data)['encoding']
    if detected_encoding is None:
        detected_encoding = 'utf-8'  # default to utf-8 if chardet fails
    try:
        return raw_data.decode(detected_encoding)
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        print(f"Failed to decode {file_path} using {detected_encoding}. Falling back to utf-8 with replacement.")
        return raw_data.decode('utf-8', errors='replace')


for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_directory):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(file_types):
            file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            print(f"Processing: {file_path}")

            content = read_file_with_encoding(file_path)
            if content is None:
                print(f"Skipping {file_path} due to undetected encoding")
                continue

            new_content, num_replacements = pattern.subn(replacement, content)

            if num_replacements > 0:
                with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                    f.write(new_content)
                count += num_replacements
                files_modified.append(file_path)

print(f"\nReport:")
print(f"Total replacements: {count}")
print("Files modified:")
for file_path in files_modified:
    print(file_path)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score -2):

Your regex contains an invalid bracket. With the assumption that you are trying to find any row where `body_value` contains `<` and `DVP` and `>`, you can try:

```
SELECT * FROM rulebook.node__body 
WHERE body_value REGEXP '.*<.*DVP.*>.*';
```

Comment: `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` are word boundaries in MySQL REGEXP. They are not intended to be literal characters in the column being searched on (as proposed in your solution).